# What is the best way to model a beam and slab bridge?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, modeling, bridges

I notice bridges designed by bridge engineers in my company invariably uses two models. One model for seismic load case and another for other load cases. I was told that some bridge elements, such as the slab and the walls have to be modelled differently, using plate elements, to capture the actual stiffness. But because it is not easy to extract the output such as bending moment, these have to be modelled as beam grillage in the non-seismic model.

As the models are different, additional effort is required to extract and combine the outputs, before processing them for design. If you are a bridge engineer, I would like to know if you have found a simpler way to model a bridge.

Comment: without going into any specifics, it is very common for all sorts of computational engineering problems that you need to develop separate modeling approaches for different aspects of the problem.  Beyond that your question is really too broad to address in this sort of forum.

Comment: Engineering models are a "chicken-and-egg" scenario. You can't make a detailed model until you have specified everything about the design, but you can't make a detailed design until you have the output from a model. So you start with a model that is light on detail but gives you a reasonable estimate of the most important quantities (e.g. forces and bending moments), use those to add more detail to the model, and "rinse and repeat" as many times as necessary.